How to deal with ´append´ like functions in lapply?
I have a function (more specifically prophet::add_regressor()) which appends values to an object. I recreated a similar function to make sure my point is clear:
add_to_a_list = function(object, item_to_add){
  
  object$a = append(object$a, item_to_add, after = T)
  
  return(object)
  
}

The tutorials using the particular function I stumbled on use the following ugly form:
stuff_to_add = c('raaa', 'ruuu', 'riii')
x = list(a = list(), b = list())

x = add_to_a_list(object = x, stuff_to_add[1])
x = add_to_a_list(object = x, stuff_to_add[2])
x = add_to_a_list(object = x, stuff_to_add[3])

str(x)

List of 2
 $ a:List of 3
  ..$ : chr "raaa"
  ..$ : chr "riii"
  ..$ : chr "ruuu"
 $ b: list()

While a for loop does the job:
stuff_to_add = c('raaa', 'ruuu', 'riii')
x = list(a = list(), b = list())

for(item in stuff_to_add){
  
  x = add_to_a_list(x, item)
  
}

str(x)


List of 2
 $ a:List of 3
  ..$ : chr "raaa"
  ..$ : chr "riii"
  ..$ : chr "ruuu"
 $ b: list()

Problem; I hate for loops in R and I always use lapply as replacement because I find it more intuitive and it is definitely faster and can be easily rewritten for parallel processing. However, I tried many variations of lapply and it does not give the expected result:
stuff_to_add = c('raaa', 'ruuu', 'riii')
x = list(a = list(), b = list())

x = lapply(stuff_to_add, function(item){
  
  add_to_a_list(x, item)
  
})

str(x)

List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a:List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr "raaa"
  ..$ b: list()
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a:List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr "ruuu"
  ..$ b: list()
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a:List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr "riii"
  ..$ b: list()

How can I assign within lapply and force it to output the object in question instead of a list?

This reads as a possible XY-problem. Are there any larger problems you want to approach that this is supposed to solve? lapply will always return a list, which can also be nested.

You should work on your pathological feelings regarding for loops. Hating them is not rational and they have there use cases. And your believe that lapply loops are faster is simply wrong.

@Roland regarding lapply vs for loop speed, would you mind pointing to a link that proves it? In my experience lapply is always faster...

Well, you can write slow code with a for loop. But that doesn’t mean a for loop is slow. It just means you wrote slow code with it. Read this answer and keep in mind that it was written before R had a JIT compiler, which optimizes code containing for loops.

This looks like a job for Reduce:
stuff_to_add <- c("raaa", "ruuu", "riii")
x <- list(a = list(), b = list())

add_to_a_list <- function(object, item_to_add) {
  object$a <- append(object$a, item_to_add, after = T)

  return(object)
}

Reduce(
  add_to_a_list,
  stuff_to_add,
  init = x
)
#> $a
#> $a[[1]]
#> [1] "raaa"
#> 
#> $a[[2]]
#> [1] "riii"
#> 
#> $a[[3]]
#> [1] "ruuu"
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> list()


Also purrr::reduce .

This is great! Thank you for pulling me out of my tunnel vision.
